# How to Interpret <type> buf(*) in Fortran MPI Data Transfer Subroutines

Tags: fortran, buffer, mpi, data-transfer

The MPI standard declares the dummy argument `buf` as follows:

```
<type> buf(*)
```

I know as a whole it declares `buf` as an array with certain type. But I never saw `<type>` is used in a declaration in Fortran before. Can anyone explain it to me or refer me to the Fortran standard that shows the grammar?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the standard you are referring to?

Comment: http://www.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/links.html

Comment: There are a lot of links in the link you gave... can you state which document you were looking at?  Preferably the page number in the PDF as well.  I want to see some context.

Comment: I actually don't know. If I know, I would have found it. The link is just an example. It may not be where you should look at.

Comment: Then where did you see that declaration of `buf`?  Often, there is a key explaining the notation these APIs will use.

Comment: What @haraldki posted is what I'm talking about.  A key to explaining the API.

Comment: MPI is not covered by Fortran standard documents. It is just an external library, implemented in a different language.

Comment: MPI-3.0 introduces a new Fortran 2008 interface called `mpi_f08`. It uses the `TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..)` feature from the TS 29113 extension to Fortran 2008 to let the compiler know that the function takes an assumed-type assumed-rank array, i.e. an array of any number of dimensions and sizes along each dimension and of any type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [MPI Standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) itself in section 2.5.5 on page 16 lines 17 to 22:

> MPI functions sometimes use arguments with a choice (or union) data type. Distinct calls to the same routine may pass by reference actual arguments of different types. The mechanism for providing such arguments will differ from language to language. For Fortran with the include file mpif.h or the mpi module, the document uses <type> to represent a choice variable